# Нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу. C++

Tags: c++, кодировка, перекодировка

Вылетает ошибка

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'symbol' was
>   corrupted.

В коде:

```
int main() {
   //system("chcp 1251");
   setlocale(0, "Russian");

   char symbol;
   cout << "Введите символ: ";
   cin  >> symbol;
   OemToAnsi(&symbol, &symbol);
   cout << symbol;
   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Ошибка появляется только тогда, когда вызываю функцию **OemToAnsi(&symbol, &symbol);**. В процессе трасировки выяснил что ошибка вылетает на последней команде **return 0;** в **main()**.

Как её исправить?

Comment: А вы не могли бы упростить пример до минимума?

Comment: просто я не знаю из  за чего именно возникает ошибка. Сама ошибка в return 0; в int main() {}

Comment: Ну, а вы всё же сделайте **минимальный** воспроизводящий пример. Например, если вы уберёте `CheckNameOfFile`, то наверняка проблема не исчезнет, а код станет проще.

Comment: Свел до минимума, ошибка изменилась

Comment: Хм. А что за функция `OemToAnsi`? Какая у неё сигнатура? Где она определена? Не могу найти её в MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему с помощью

```
OemToAnsiBuff(&symbol, &symbol, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char symbol;
> cout << "Введите символ: ";
> cin  >> symbol;
> OemToAnsi(&symbol, &symbol);
> ```

Думаю, что она хочет нормальную строку, а не символ:

```
char symbol[2] = {0, 0};
cout << "Введите символ: ";
cin  >> *symbol;
OemToAnsi(symbol, symbol);
```